# SSRS Hidden Expression in a Tablix throws an error but Tablix does not have a hidden expression configured

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is throwing the following error:

```
    Error   2   [rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix27’ 
    contains an error: 
    The query returned no rows for the dataset. The expression therefore 
    evaluates to null.
```

Tablix 27 has `Visibility` set to `show` so there's no `hide expression`. Any idea on how to get rid of the error or any pointers that can lead me in the right direction?

what could be causing the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, so I thought I'd post if anyone else came across the same problem.

The query that populated the Tablix was returning `null` and because of this the error was being thrown. I was able to handle the error by right clicking on the Tablix affected and going to its `Tablix Properties` and then adding the following expression under the hide field: `=CountRows("MyDatasetNameHere") < 1`

This evaluates to true which in turn hides the Tablix and the error is no longer thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that you may need to check the settings in the Visibility tab of the Properties dialog box - it is confusing because there are two places that visibility can be set in. You may be looking at this location:

[image]

But try going here instead by right clicking on the upper left hand corner of your tablix:

[image]

Click on Tablix Properties, then take a look at the Visibility tab and see if there is anything entered in the expressions box:

[image]

EDIT: I can't actually replicate your problem, so I'm afraid my ability to help further won't be great. My only other advice is to make sure you are looking at the correct tablix and to try copy and pasting the tablix, then deleting the original.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the Row  in Design view select Visibility and select Show. Most often you have a previous report to show visibility based on an expression that is causing problem.